# Function doesn't update new valuables

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, prompt

I'm fairly new to javascript and got stuck onto something. The problem is that the prompt in the following code never gets updated to the actual valuables, while the 'console.log' does for some reason. I'd really like to know why this happens, and if there's any way to make it work so that the prompt will update like the 'console.log' does. I've tried to move the positions of the variables a bit in the code, but as I'm not an expert, I'm not sure if the positions of the variables were ever correct.

Help would be very appreciated, let me know if there's something not clear enough!

```
var alive = true;    
var destinationArray = ["town ", "areas ", "bosses"];
var destinationArraySet = 1;
var allDestination = destinationArray.slice(0, destinationArraySet).join(' ').trim();
var userDestinationPrompt = ("Where would you like to go? Available places: \n" + allDestination +".");

var userDestination = function () {
    allDestination = destinationArray.slice(0, destinationArraySet).join(' ').trim();
    console.log(allDestination);
    userDestinationAnswer = prompt(userDestinationPrompt).toUpperCase();
    destinationArraySet++;
};

while (alive) {
    userDestination();
}
```

Comment: `userDestinationPrompt` is constant here : it will not be updated when `allDestination` changes... You should make use a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"userDestination" is new function.

And value of "userDestinationPrompt" has been set before function called.

Set value inside the function will solve your issue.

```
var userDestination = function () {
    allDestination = destinationArray.slice(0, destinationArraySet).join(' ').trim();
    console.log(allDestination);
    var userDestinationPrompt = ("Where would you like to go? Available places: \n" + allDestination +".");
    userDestinationAnswer = prompt(userDestinationPrompt).toUpperCase();
    destinationArraySet++;
};
```

Comment: I remember doing this before, but the I didn't like it how I have to search it up completely if I wanted to change the prompt, so I made it a variable outside the function. But I wasn't  aware that 'allDestination' didn't get updated inside the prompt unless the whole prompt itself got updated. At least I know now how it works now, thanks for the answer :).